# Add a new item to html-select list without leaving the page. How?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, user-interface, html-select

I've always wondered what is the best way to add a new item to html-select in a website.
Yes, this may sound silly but it is a great problem from the usability perspective. I don't want the user to be taken to a new page every time they need to add new item to a html-select.

I like the way Google Reader and Gmail handle this problem in there "add folder" and "add label" functionality. I would like to mimic that but i have no clue how they did that.

I'm using jQuery, so any reference to plugins, code examples or tutorials are welcome.
I would like it to be as modular as possible so i can reuse it anywhere.

I'm using ASP.NET 3.5 web-forms, Microsoft Access 2003, jQuery, IIS 5 and Win XP Professional as web server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a [jquery select plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/) that might help you with this. I've manipulated select lists client side and had no problem with subsequent form-submits but you'd need to do some experiments w asp.net

Comment: thanks. that might be what i'm looking for as it works with json.

Answer (score 0):

The standard technique of doing this is called [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), which basically means replacing only parts of the page. [JQuery ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) and maybe a [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ajaxjquery.html) should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake for this scenario is to add the item on client (using jQuery or plain javascript). It may look that it works until the next post-back. Unfortunately the Asp.NET post-back model does not allow to alter the controls contents on client side only. So basicaly there are two choices:

- Use ajax (the simplest would be to
  use an UpdatePanel)
- Make a normal
  postback to add the item (simple and
  fast to code, if performance is not
  an issue - for intranet applications
  for example)